# Check day of week and change label accordingly

Tags: vb.net

I'm new here having used the website before to get out of sticky university projects - ever greatful.

However this time it's just a side project.

What I'm trying to do is change the text in a label based on a) the day of the week and b) the time of the day.

It will be used for displaying different radio presenters show names on different days and different times on those days.

Here's what I've got so far, which works if DayOfWeek.Sunday = False but not vice versa as it should.

```
If DayOfWeek.Sunday = True Then
    Select
        Case TimeOfDay
        Case "13:00:00" To "14:00:00"
            Show.Text = "The Indie Show"
    End Select
End If
```

The clock works as it should so no problems there.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`DayOfWeek.Sunday` is a fixed value, you need `DateTime.Now` to look at the current date and time.

```
    Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Now

    If today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        If today.Hour = 13 OrElse (today.Hour = 14 AndAlso today.Minute = 0 AndAlso today.Second = 0) Then
            Show.Text = "The Indie Show"
        End If
    End If
```

It is much easier to write, and more common, to look for a time just before 14:00:

```
    If today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
        If today.Hour = 13 Then
            Show.Text = "The Indie Show"
        End If
    End If
```